# Converting dataframe to Gspread list format in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to log entries from my weatherstation. I can gather the data I need in a pandas dataframe, but I have to convert it to a specific list format to append multiple inputs to a google sheet using Gspread.

The dataframe.to.list() function gives me this format:

`[[18, '2020-12-29 00:59:44'], [17, '2020-12-29 01:59:45'],` etc.

However the append function to Gspread requires this format:

`inputdata = ["17", "2020-12-29 01:59:45"]`

and I believe that I can only enter one list item at a time.

I love to get some help regarding how to convert the list format to the specified Gspread format and how to append all data points in an automated way. My limited knowledge believes a For loop is required for this.

[image: screenshot of my situation]

Comment: There must be a setValues in gspread which accepts a 2D array.

Comment: For tasks like this, I use `gspread_dataframe` which allows you to append a data frame to an existing Google Sheet.

Comment: @It_is_Chris thank you! this works, but how are you able to append without deleting prior logged data?

Comment: @Theodorska you read the existing file then filter for `nan` which will give you the index the the first empty row. I will submit an answer with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import gspread
import gspread_dataframe as gd

gc = gspread.service_account(filename=r'json file path from google api')
sheet = gc.open("File name").worksheet('Sheet1')
Google_frame = gd.get_as_dataframe(sheet)
# find the index of the first null row
idx = existing[existing['some column name'].isna()].head(1).index[0]
# the length of the frame you want to append to the Google sheet plus the index
# df is the frame that you want to append to the google sheet
idx_to = len(df) + idx
# use iloc to append the two frames together
Google_frame.iloc[idx:idx_to, :] = df.to_numpy()
# update the Google Sheet
gd.set_with_dataframe(sheet, Google_frame)
```